# How to subtract two rows of ndarray matrix in Rust?

Tags: rust, numpy-ndarray

```
use ndarray::Array;

fn main() {
    let random = Array::ones((5, 3));
    println!("{:?}", random);

    let test = random.row(0) - random.row(1);
    println!("{:?}", test);
}
```

When running this Rust code, I get the compile error:

```
error[E0369]: cannot subtract `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&_>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>` from `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&_>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
```

I think this is because views can't be used to create a new variable, but how do I actually fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to borrow the rows:

```rust
use ndarray::Array;

fn main() {
    let random: Array<i32, _> = Array::ones((5, 3));
    println!("{:?}", random);

    let test = &random.row(0) - &random.row(1);
    println!("{:?}", test);
}
```